# Working with embeeded documents and multiple schemas in one collection, mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, model

I have the following mongoose schemas for a MongoDB:

1. User

```
{
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    ...
}

userSchema.methods.verifyPassword(password) {
 //Verify password match
}
```

2. Customer

```
{
    user: [User],
    firstname: { type: String, required: true },
    lastname: { type: String, required: true },
    ...
}
```

3. Company

```
{
    user: [User],
    name: { type: String, required: true },
   ...
}
```

I've decided to store the models 'Customer' and 'Company' in the same collection 'Users', as they are account data with only a few different attributes.
I'm implementing a method for login. The problem came when I try to verify the password, how can I implement a unique method for getting this embedded user.password?

Company.findOne() seems to work and Customer.findOne() too. How do I choose one? (I don't know if the login is for a company or customer, only have the email and password). If I try to implement a User model and later User.findOne(), then I can't access user.user.password due to the schema User.

Is there a right way to do it that I am not seeing?

Comment: Is the email unique across app? Or company and customer can have same email?

Comment: Exactly, email is unique across app

Comment: If you want to keep the same data models then simply do a findOne on both. Since the email is unique only one of them will return a document. And you can verify password on that document.

Comment: Really, I wanted to keep the two kinds of documents (Customer and Company) in the same collection.  My thought was to use the user embedded in different documents and schemas. This way, I won't need a collection for every new role I create and I can use the same CRUD methods without thinking about User model.

Comment: If the email is unique, then you can simply have both the user roles in one collection and based on the user email and password entered the data will be matched and the matching user will be returned for having a successful login.